# css visibility not changing on hover event

Tags: css

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094893/changing-visibility-property-in-css) post to make my hover work. But solution there is not working for me.

I have HTML like

```
<div id="top">
<div id="first">
</div>
<div id="second">
</div>
<div id="third">
    <div id="hiddentext">1st div is hovered</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have big css file...you can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hrishikeshp19/Q5zt2/16/)

Can anyone help me getting my hiddentext visible on hover of "first" div.
​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write like this

```
#first:hover + #second + #third > #hiddentext{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Q5zt2/17/

**Updated**

write like this:

```
#first:hover ~ #third #hiddentext{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5zt2/20/

Comment: Thats great. Thanks a ton. But why? and how come?

Comment: because you define + selector wrongly check this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Comment: Two questions: why are #first and #second are needed there? and Is there a better way to achieve the same functionality using css only?

Comment: for your second question check http://jsfiddle.net/Q5zt2/20/ for your second question check & read the link of w3c which i give you.

Comment: These fiddles no longer work.  What kind of HTML structure did them use to demonstrate?

Comment: @NewAlexandria the HTMl structure is same as above check this http://jsbin.com/ajeyub/1/